# Combining AND and OR statements

Tags: excel

```
NA  NA  NA  88  88  99  NA
NA  NA  1   88  88  0   Y
NA  NA  1   88  88  0   Y
NA  NA  1   88  88  0   Y
```

I have the above columns. I am using the following formula to filter:

```
=IF(AND(A1="NA", C1="NA"), "NA", IF(OR(A1>3, C1>3), "Y", "N"))
```

That formula seems to work for Row 1, however for Rows 2, 3, 4 I am getting the wrong output in Column G: G1 should be NA, but G2, G3, G4 should be "N" given that the value in C2, C3, and C4 is less than 4.

Comment: `OR(A1>3, C1>3)`, either one is true will return true which will give you `Y`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NA` is `>` than 3.  so `A1>3` is true and it returns "Y"

To get around you need to add a check for numbers:

```
=IF(AND(A1="NA", C1="NA"), "NA", IF(OR(AND(A1>3,ISNUMBER(A1)), AND(C1>3,ISNUMBER(C1))), "Y", "N"))
```

Comment: Does Excel return `TRUE`  for `NA > 3` just because `NA` isn't a number, so it therefore just returns `TRUE`...? (...but that doesn't make sense, so I wonder why it's returning true for `NA>3`.)

Comment: Yes Excel will see any text as greater than any number. @BruceWayne